# bind_param mysql

Tags: php

Есть код создающий запись в БД:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chat (data, frequency, snr, drift, grid, dbm, w, by, loc, km, mi) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $data, $frequency, $snr, $drift, $grid, $dbm, $w, $by, $loc, $km, $mi);
$stmt->execute();
```

Так вот он не работает. Если в bind_param оставить 3 и меньше переменных все работает, больше - нет. Вот ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in
>   D:\open_server_5_3_0_ultimate\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   D:\open_server_5_3_0_ultimate\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on
>   line 87

Может кто-то поможет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что такое $conn? что находится в index.php в той строке?

Comment: после prepare сделайте $conn->error_list  и посмотрите что выдаст.
А лучше сделайте 
if(!$stmt){
  print_r($conn->error_list);
}

Comment: `BY` зарезервированное слово в мускуле.